# Is there a way to get x-mouse-type scrolling under the cursor for child windows within one program window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, scrolling, xmouse

I've been messing with X-mouse setups, to enable scrolling for whatever is under the cursor, regardless of whether it has the focus or not. I've found several ways to get this to work between various 'parent' windows (Win7's built-in mouse options, WizMouse, etc), but I've found nothing that will do the same thing with (for example) several child windows with spreadsheets, open at the same time in one parent Excel window.  I have the spreadsheets set up so that two are visible in the window at the same time, but I always have to click on either one to scroll it up and down. I'd love to be able to scroll these just by moving the mouse and doing the scroll, without the extra focus-change-click.  I am not a big fan of running separate parent windows for each spreadsheet, which I realize would be something of a workaround. I'd rather keep the single parent Excel window, but still have X-mouse functionality within it.

Anyone know of any way to achieve this?  I'd call it "XMouse for Child Windows".

Comment: Interesting.  I could of sworn they fixed this long ago.  I'm noticing the same issue.  But not on my laptop though. . .

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a neat little free program called [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) which does exactly what you want. I used to use Freewheel, but it doesn’t work well in Windows 7 (though it works fine in Windows XP).

Answer (score 0):

[Taekwindow](http://taekwindow.net/) is probably what you are looking for.

From their site:

```
In full detail, Taekwindow allows you to do the following:

    move a window by grabbing it anywhere (not just the title bar) while holding the Alt key, and then dragging with the left mouse button;
    resize a window by grabbing it anywhere (not just the tiny little border) while holding the Alt key, and then dragging with the right mouse button;
    move a maximized window between monitors by Alt-dragging;
    use the scroll wheel on the window under the cursor, instead of the currently focused window;
    push a window to the background by middle-clicking on its title bar.

All these features can be configured to your liking.
```

Comment: Thanks, but Taekwindow works like all the other utilities I've tried. It handles scrolling between parent windows, but not multiple child windows within a single parent.  Some of the grabbing features are interesting, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [TXmouse](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) some time ago. It's extremely lightweight. You have to download and executable, and run it - red x will appear in a tray.

Comment: Thanks, I tried TXmouse too, it's also just good for parent windows, not children. Children don't behave! (ain't it the truth)